# How to set the plot's xtick range even though it has data outside the range?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

**I'm working on making a plot which compares two targeted cat kinds against others, and  I want the xtick range up to 500000, here is the code:**

```
wanted_breed = ['アメリカンショートヘア','ブリティッシュショートヘア']
df['breed_pool'] = [x if x in wanted_breed else 'others' for x in df['breed']]
sns.set(font='Yu Gothic')
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
g=sns.lineplot(x = "price",
             y = "Age",
             hue = 'breed_pool',
             units = 'breed',
             estimator = None,
             palette = 'Set2',
             data = df,ax=ax)
g.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.6, 0.8), ncol=1)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,500000,100000),rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

part of the lines of 'others' over 40000 still in the plot

[image: part of the lines of 'others' over 50000 still in the plot]

Will it be possible to cut the plot by the xtick up to 500000, even there's data over 500000? And I don't need the empty space. Thank you!
**Really appreciate your help!!!**

Comment: Did you try using plt.xlim() ?

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just use [plt.xlim()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) to limit the x axis of your plot.